# Using atomics to reduce amount of mutex locks in multithreading c++ code

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

My multithreaded code has 3 different sections that can be described like this:

(1)unprotected by mutex:
This part of code is only doing work on local and thread_local variables as well as global variables that are guaranteed to not change during multithreading.

(2)protected by shared_lock:
This part can access but not modify a bunch of global datastructures

(3)protected by unique_lock:
This part can access and modify(sometimes destructively) a bunch of global datastructures

I have only one global shared_mutex which is locked by the locks.

Everything is working fine but I noticed that I have a bunch of places looking like this

```
struct MyStruct {
  uint64_t counter;
  //some other fields
};

unordered_map<uint64_t, MyStruct> map;
shared_mutex mutex;

void someFunction(uint64_t id) {
  shared_lock lock(mutex);

  auto it = map.find(id);
  if(it == map.end()) return;
  MyStruct &s = it->second;
  
  uint64_t counterValue = s.counter;
  doSomeWork(counterValue);//old value of counter is used

  mutex.unlock_shared();
  mutex.lock();
  //if we don't find id in map, it means that s was deleted during lock transition
  //id is never reused for a different struct
  if(map.find(id) == map.end()) return;
  s.counter += 1;
  mutex.unlock();
  mutex.lock_shared();

  if(map.find(id) == map.end()) return;

  doSomeMoreWork();//counter is not used anymore
}
```

seems wasteful to do a bunch of relocks to increase a single counter, so I want to change counter to be atomic and have something like:

```
struct MyStruct {
  atomic<uint64_t> counter;
  //some other fields
};

unordered_map<uint64_t, MyStruct> map;
shared_mutex mutex;

void someFunction(uint64_t id) {
  shared_lock lock(mutex);

  auto it = map.find(id);
  if(it == map.end()) return;
  MyStruct &s = it->second;
  
  uint64_t counterValue = s.counter.fetch_add(1);
  doSomeWork(counterValue);//old value of counter is used
  doSomeMoreWork();//counter is not used anymore
}
```

I have no experience with atomics. Is this gonna work properly? Are there some potential problems to watch out for? Also there is a bunch of different memory orders I can provide for fetch_add:

```
memory_order_relaxed
memory_order_consume
memory_order_acquire
memory_order_release
memory_order_acq_rel
memory_order_seq_cst
```

what is the right one here?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: As Jan's answer shows, CAS makes it possible to attempt an increment which can only succeed if `counter%5==0` is still true.  You can compose any single-variable RMW from a CAS retry loop, anything you can express as a pure function of one input.

Comment: You guys are correct; I've deleted my comment.  I should have used an example with two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use atomics for this purpose.
In fact, you could even keep the old syntax of `s.counter += 1` with a `std::atomic<std::uint64_t>`.
However, this would use `std::memory_order::seq_cst`, which may be beyond your needs.

It's overall a better solution because the code is simpler and likely much faster.
Note that many architectures (e.g. x86_64, ARM64) have hardware support for atomic operations.
On x86_64, an atomic fetch-add is simply an `add` instruction with a `lock` prefix.
This is much faster than locking a mutex.

#### Which memory order to choose

If the only thing you need is a counter which is incremented atomically, it's sufficient to use `std::memory_order::relaxed`.
However, when in doubt, just go with `seq_cst`.
Which memory order you need depends on what other operations are performed on the atomic.
It's always about the big picture, you cannot decide it for one operation in isolation.

#### What about more complex operations

On a side note, since this has been mentioned in the comments, you can perform operations which are more complex than `+=` using a [Compare-and-swap (CAS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) operation (in C++: [`compare_exchange_xxx`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange)).

For example, to perform `if ((counter%5)==0) counter++;` atomically:

```cpp
std::uint64_t expected = counter;
while (expected % 5 == 0 && counter.compare_exchange_weak(expected, expected + 1)) {}
```

Comment: I edited my question to provide a more complex example.

Comment: @eX_ploit make a new question in which you ask how to perform this complex operation atomically. Otherwise you're asking two questions in one.